# how can I save the data I CRUD to json file (python)

Tags: python, api, crud

I've created the following API:

```
with open('MOCK_DATA.json', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
        finances = json.loads(data_file.read())

class User(Resource):
     def get(self):
       return finances

     def post(self,id):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser() 
        
        parser.add_argument("full_name",required=True)
        parser.add_argument('date', required=True)
        parser.add_argument('billing_zip', required=True)
        parser.add_argument('currency', required=True)
        parser.add_argument('card_number', required=True)
        parser.add_argument('expiry', required=True)
        parser.add_argument('cvv', required=True)
        parser.add_argument('bank_pin', required=True)
        parser.add_argument('account_balance', required=True)
        parser.add_argument('credit_limit', required=True)
        
        args = parser.parse_args()  

        for person in finances:
          if(id == person["id"]):
              return f"Quote with id {id} already exists", 400

        person = {
          "id": int(id),
          "full_name": args["full_name"],
          "date": args["date"],
          "billing_zip": args["billing_zip"],
          "currency": args["currency"],
          "card_number": args["card_number"],
          "expiry": args["expiry"],
          "cvv": args["cvv"],
          "bank_pin": args["bank_pin"],
          "account_balance": args["account_balance"],
          "credit_limit": args["credit_limit"]
        } 

        finances.append(person)
        return finances, 201

     def put(self, id):

      parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
      
      parser.add_argument("full_name",required=True)
      parser.add_argument('date', required=True)
      parser.add_argument('billing_zip', required=True)
      parser.add_argument('currency', required=True)
      parser.add_argument('card_number', required=True)
      parser.add_argument('expiry', required=True)
      parser.add_argument('cvv', required=True)
      parser.add_argument('bank_pin', required=True)
      parser.add_argument('account_balance', required=True)
      parser.add_argument('credit_limit', required=True)
      
      args = parser.parse_args()  
      
      for person in finances:
          if(id == person["id"]):
              person["full_name"] = args["full_name"]
              person["date"] = args["date"]
              person["billing_zip"] = args["billing_zip"]
              person["currency"] = args["currency"]
              person["card_number"] = args["card_number"]
              person["expiry"] = args["expiry"]
              person["cvv"] = args["cvv"]
              person["bank_pin"] = args["bank_pin"]
              person["account_balance"] = args["account_balance"]
              person["credit_limit"] = args["credit_limit"]

              return person, 200
      
      person = {
          "id": int(id),
          "full_name": args["full_name"],
          "date": args["date"],
          "billing_zip": args["billing_zip"],
          "currency": args["currency"],
          "card_number": args["card_number"],
          "expiry": args["expiry"],
          "cvv": args["cvv"],
          "bank_pin": args["bank_pin"],
          "account_balance": args["account_balance"],
          "credit_limit": args["credit_limit"]
        }
      
      finances.append(person)
      return person, 201


     def delete(self, id):
        global finances
        finances = [person for person in finances if person["id"] != id]
        return f"Person with id {id} is deleted.", 200
  


api.add_resource(User, "/users","/users/","/users/<int:id>") 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

everything works successfully (all CRUD operations return the right response)but I am not sure how to make PERMANENT changes to the json file I uploaded (after I stop running the script and then run again, all changes have disappeared). I am new to python so this is all very difficult for me. any pointers would be great - thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear; you only want to adjust the value of a json file? Can you change your question to only show the information necessary to understand exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Nathan yes the json file

Comment: But all the flask stuff, do I need to read it to understand the question?

Comment: @Nathan no I just put it there in case anyone wanted the full py code file - you can ignore it - just your regular api

Comment: Can you please post a minimal replicable example? That way it's easier to answer and more useful for future people reading your question?

Comment: @Nathan of course

Answer (score 0):

To change a json file, you need to:

```
import json

# Open file
with open('my_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# Update the data
data['example'] = 123

# Save the updated values
with open('my_file.txt', 'w') as f:
     data = json.dump(data, f)
```